# Difference in Data type conversion methods in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can convert the data type of a column in the following ways

Option 1

```
df['column_name']=df.column_name.astype(str)
```

Option 2

```
df['column_name']=df['column_name'].astype(str)
```

My question - is there any difference betwwn option 1 and 2. If so, which one is better?

Comment: 2nd one is better , if you name your columns like 'sum', 'count' , you will see the first one raise error

Comment: @Wen i second you. :) also if the column name has spaces, the 2nd one serves better.

Answer (score 1):

lets take an example:

```
>>df

Row Labels col1 col2
abc12        1    2
def34        3    4
ghi56        5    5
```

now if you apply astype as below:

```
df['Row Labels']=df['Row Labels'].astype(str)
```

you can see that the above column `Row Labels` has been converted into a str by using:

```
df.applymap(type).eq(str).all()
```

However if you try with option 1:

```
df['Row Labels']= df.Row Labels.astype('str')
```

you will face:

> df['Row Labels']=df.Row Labels.astype('str')

```
                            ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Similarly most of the operations doesnot work well with `df.col_name` as opposed to `df['col_name']`

Hope that answers your question.